# I wanted to create search functionality common method

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, user-defined-functions

```
Sub SearchMenu(varSearchItem, varApp)
   ` Call LinkClick("name","Search")
    Call WebEditSet("name","searchTerm", varSearchItem)
    If LCase(varApp) = "bk" Then
        Call ImageClick("title","Search")
    Else`your text`
        Call WebButtonClick("name","Search")
    End If
    ''clicks link on search results page
    Call LinkClick("name",varSearchItem)
End Sub
```

I wanted to create a user defined search method in Java that can be used by multiple applications in Selenium for web applications. I am new to selenium. I wanted to pass two argument. I am converting UFT script sub routine for search menu to search method.

This is my code in UFT I wanted to rewrite in Java. I need help to write in the Java Selenium.